# MySQL how to query customers but skip when firstname and lastname match

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, self-join

MySQL

Imagine a prepaid card issuing company.

A user could signup many times.

One user can have many cards.

```
CREATE TABLE users ( 
  id int primary key,
  govid varchar(255),
  firstname varchar(255),
  lastname varchar(255),
  address varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE card (
  id int primary key,
  cardnumber varchar(16), 
  balance int, 
  user_id integer
);
```

Want a list of users that 
1. have the same govid 
2. have more than 10 cards 
3. only if first and last name do not match

My attempt:

```
select u.govid, count(*)
from card c
join users u on u.id=c.user_id
/*join users u2 on u2.id=u.id and u2.firstname<>u.firstname and u2.lastname<>u.lastname ?*/
group by u.govid
having count(*)>10
```

I cant figure out how to put in requirement #3?

Comment: Have you added `where u.firstname != u.lastname` before the `group by` clause?

Comment: Yes I did in the above attempt, its in comments, was unsure if that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Join the original table with the users who have more than 10 cards and check for the firstname and lastname condition.

```
select u1.govid,u1.firstname,u1.lastname,u2.firstname,u2.lastname
from users u1 
join (select * from users
      where govid in (select u.govid
                      from users u
                      join card c on u.id=c.user_id
                      group by u.govid
                      having count(*)>10
                     ) 
      ) u2 on u1.govid = u2.govid
where u2.firstname<>u1.firstname and u2.lastname<>u1.lastname
```